# Weird C++ array access

Tags: c++

Here's the program.

```
#include <iostream>
int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {
    int a[4] = {10, 11, 18, 32};
    int x = 2[a];
    int y = a[2];
    std::cout << "x = " << x << '\n';
    std::cout << "y = " << y << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

The output is as follows.

```
x = 18
y = 18
```

How is "2[a]" legal syntax? What is happening in this program to make this work? Even https://cdecl.org/ says 2[a] is a syntax error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/381549/10548514 this is why it works in C, not sure about C++

Comment: Ah, thank you very much!
I compiled the program with g++ -std=c++17, and it worked as it would in C. This makes sense.

Comment: `cdecl` is for declarations; this isn't a declaration